# $\omega=\frac{v_t}{r}$ using this equation only prove that constant angular velocity is possible

Tags: rotational-kinematics

Is it possible to have constant angular velocity since according to $\omega=\frac{v_t} {r}$ angular velocity is directly propotional to tangential velocity and since  tangential velocity is a vector and is always changing directions in uniform rotational motion, therefore we will get different values of angular velocity depending on the direction of tangential velocity? So we can't get constant angular velocity?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, can you please add details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in circular motion

$$\vert\vec\omega\vert=\frac{\vert\vec{v_t}\vert} {r}$$

Here the magnitude of angular velocity vector is directly proportional to magnitude of tangential velocity vector.

Comment: What about the direction of angular velocity, since it is a pseudovector right?

Comment: In circular motion, the direction of angular velocity is perpendicular to the plane containing $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$

Answer (score 1):

$\omega=\frac{v_t}{r}$ is not a vector equation for $\omega$

the vector equation is $\vec v_t = \vec r$x$\vec \omega$
The direction of $\omega$ is perpendicular to $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v_t} $. that is *perpendicular to the plane containing vectors $\vec r$ and $\vec{v_t} $*. so, as long as $r$ and $v_t$ continue to remain in the same plane, $\omega$ would not change direction. Thus, for a constant $r$ and $v$, $\omega$ is a constant.

A large percentage of rotational motion is planar motion. That is : the particle rotate in one plane and $\vec r$ and $\vec v$ remain in the same plane. Thus $\vec\omega$ remains in one direction (perpendicular to the plane).

Comment: What do you mean by"remain in one plane"?

Comment: @Rishab Navaneet If $\vec{v}$ reverses its direction then $\vec\omega$ would definitely change

Comment: @zheer : only one plane can pass touching two vectors. By ''remaining in one plane" I meant that as the particle rotates, the plane defined by vectors  $\vec r$ and $\vec v_t$ does not change. I should've said "continue to remain in the same plane ". Thanks for that.... *Usually rotational motions are planar motion. ie: particle moves in a single plane and radius and velocity vectors remain in same plane*

Comment: @Sarcasm : You're right... I didn't

Comment: @Sarcasm : You're right.... But during rotational motions, $\vec v$ alone doesn't shift to negative direction. The tail of $\vec v$ is always at the head of $\vec r$ and they rotate together.... so such abrupt shift ($\vec r$ shifts but $\vec v$ don't) does not happen.

Comment: @Rishab Navaneet It can shift if there exists an external force in a tangential direction which may be opposite in direction of velocity vector

Comment: yes... then $\omega$ is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

Angular speed is defined as $\omega=\frac{d \theta}{dt}$

Since $d\theta=\frac{ds}{r}$ (see picture)
[image]
we have $\omega=\frac{ds}{dt}\frac1r=\frac{v}{r}$

In uniform circular motion, the **r** does not change, nor **v**. Thus $\omega$ must be constant.

Now this is a scalar equation. We can define vector equation as:
$$\vec \omega \times \vec r=\vec v$$
Or
$$\vec r \times \vec v = \vec \omega$$
You have said, that in circular motion, the velocity vector changes, which is true. But so does postion vector $\vec r$. Now how do we know for sure angular velocity is constant at all times?
$$\frac {d}{dt}[\vec \omega]=\frac{d}{dt}[\vec r \times \vec v]=\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\times\vec v+\vec r\times \frac{d\vec v}{dt}=0\\\biggl[\frac{d\vec v}{dt}\parallel\vec r,\frac{d\vec r}{dt}=\vec v\biggr]$$
It implies that omega is indeed constant.